# Delayed_job: Undefined method error on any call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I have a rails 3.0.5 app that was working just fine with delayed_job 2.1.4.

It's been a few weeks since I touched the app, but I just went to tweak it and noticed that delayed_job is broken. Specifically, any call to delayed_job returns an "undefined method" error on the method after delay. (eg StudentMailer.delay.student_mail('test') returns "undefined method" on "student_mail") I cannot figure out why. A few things:

- Replacing StudentMailer.delay.student_mail('test') with StudentMailer.student_mail('test').deliver delivers the mail just fine.
- Have not changed any gem versions on the site, they've been locked since development
- RVM has been uninstalled & reinstalled
- Happens across all mailer methods

Code & error below:

MAILER:

```
class StudentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def course_signup(email, password, course, enrolment)
    @email = email
    @password = password
    @course = course
    @enrolment = enrolment
    @student = Student.where(:email => email).first
    if (@student.user.first_name && @enrolment.student.user.last_name) then
      @username = @student.first_name.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, '').downcase + '.' + @student.last_name.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, '').downcase
    else
      @username = "fcuser#{@student.id}"
    end
    mail(:to => email, :from => ENV['ACCOUNTS_EMAIL'], :subject => "You have been enrolled as a student for #{course}", :content_type => 'text/plain') 
  end
end
```

MODEL (Mailer called on after_save)

```
  after_create {
    studentmailer = StudentMailer
    #studentmailer.course_signup(self.student.email, self.purchase.course).deliver
    randompass = RandomPassword.random_string(20)
    randomGatewayPass = RandomPassword.random_string(8)
    studentmailer.delay.course_signup(self.student.email, randomGatewayPass, self.purchase.course, self)
    self.save   }
```

CONFIG/BOOT.RB

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'

require 'rubygems'
gemfile = File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
begin
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = gemfile
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.setup
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound => e
  STDERR.puts e.message
  STDERR.puts "Try running `bundle install`."
  exit!
end if File.exist?(gemfile)
```

DELAYED JOB ERROR:

> {undefined method `course_signup' for #<Class:0x007fbcf61850c8>
>   /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:6:in`
>   perform'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in
>   `invoke_job'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in`
>   block (2 levels) in
>   run'\n/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in
>   `timeout'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in`
>   block in
>   run'\n/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in
>   `realtime'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in`
>   run'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:177:in
>   `reserve_and_run_one_job'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:104:in`
>   block in
>   work_off'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in
>   `times'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in`
>   work_off'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:78:in
>   `block (2 levels) in
>   start'\n/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in`
>   realtime'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in
>   `block in
>   start'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in`
>   loop'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in
>   `start'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:104:in`
>   run'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:83:in
>   `block in
>   run_process'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:249:in`
>   call'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:249:in
>   `block in
>   start_proc'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:197:in`
>   call'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:197:in
>   `call_as_daemon'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:253:in`
>   start_proc'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:293:in
>   `start'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in`
>   run'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons.rb:195:in
>   `block in
>   run_proc'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in`
>   call'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in
>   `catch_exceptions'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/daemons-1.1.4/lib/daemons.rb:194:in`
>   run_proc'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:81:in
>   `run_process'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:75:in`
>   block in
>   daemonize'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:73:in
>   `times'\n/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:73:in`
>   daemonize'\nscript/delayed_job:5:in `' | 2011-09-06 07:42:21 |
>   NULL      | 2011-09-06 07:43:00 | NULL      | 2011-09-06 07:40:07 |
>   2011-09-06 07:43:00 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was Googling the same issue, and I found a fix for this(it worked for me).

add these two lines to the head of your config/application.rb

> require 'yaml'
>
> YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'

then, restart your server(webrick/thin/whatever) and delayed_job
(bundle exec ./script/delayed_job restart)

done.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you are using thin, try doing "bundle exec thin start". It worked for me.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with an app deployed to Heroku. Any idea how to fix it there? Also, where do you put `bundle exec thin start`? Just in terminal?

Comment: Same issue. I'm trying to send a email via delayed_job via the console for testing (which isn't using thin).

Comment: me too. no one's figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

try to change method definition

```
 def self.course_signup
```

or

```
 studentmailer = StudentMailer.new
```

because now you call method from class but method belongs to object